# Stripe: "Your request was in test mode but used a non test card"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I have recently switched my Stripe accounts, and in the process also switched from test to live. I persistently get an error from Stripe when I submit a real credit card for payment:

```
StripeResponse.error.message = "Your request was in test mode but used a non test card"
```

Checking the variables:

```
$ heroku config -r production
>> ...
STRIPE_API_KEY:              sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY:           pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The values of these keys match the values in my Stripe settings. My Stripe dashboard is also toggled to live. It seems like there's something left over in my app from when I was testing, but I can't figure out what it is.

What could be telling Stripe that I'm in test mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using your live API key

```
heroku run console
```

Once connected to the console

```
puts Stripe.api_key
```

Does the output match your live API key?

Comment: I have checked it in my Heroku settings, and it is indeed the live api and publishable keys. Is it possible that dashboard is wrong?

Comment: Clarified my original question.

Comment: Have restarted your Heroku dynos (or redeployed) since updating the API keys?

Comment: I've redeployed about a dozen times in the debugging process, so yes.

Comment: Maybe its using a hardcoded key from somewhere else? Have you verified that `Stripe.api_key` shows the right key in the heroku console?

Comment: Hmmm... How could I show that? What would the specific command be?

Comment: `heroku run console` and then once in the console `Stripe.api_key`

Comment: Yep, it was wrong. Thank you. I hardcoded both keys into an initializer and everything is working now. But now I have both keys in an initializer on my private repository. Surely there's a better solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, if you want to put your Stripe.api_key check in your answer, I'd be happy to upvote.